# Gmail blocking e-mail from my personal domain

Tags: sendmail, gmail, opendkim

For some reason Gmail has started blocking e-mail from my domain (flanigan.net).

I have had DKIM (opendkim), DMARC (opendmarc), and SPF implemented for some time. I am not on any of the SPAM or issues list that I can find. I have no history of bad behavior or issues, and I have no problem with sending e-mail to any other domain (yahoo, outlook.com, etc, etc).

The message I get back is unhelpful. I have filled in all the forms and done all the Gmail help guides I can find.

I just do e-mail from home use and for some friends and charities I support. All said and done only 40 users. Again no history of issues or SPAM.

Bounced Message Headers below:

> Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
>   Date: 2016-12-16 11:10
>   From: Mail Delivery Subsystem 
>   To:
>
> The original message was received at Fri, 16 Dec 2016 11:10:19 -0500 from     >ns1.flanigan.net [IPv6:::1]
>
> ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors ----- >>
>        (reason: 550-5.7.1 [2600:3c02::f03c:91ff:fe89:bda4      12] Our 
>   system has detected that)
>
> ----- Transcript of session follows ----- ... while talking to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.:
>    DATA
>    550-5.7.1 [2600:3c02::f03c:91ff:fe89:bda4      12] Our system has 
>   detected that
>   550-5.7.1 this message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam  550-5.7.1 sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit <<< 550-5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError
>   550 5.7.1  for more information. u1si2266860ywd.269 - gsmtp
>   554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns; ns1.flanigan.net
>   Arrival-Date: Fri, 16 Dec 2016 11:10:19 -0500

Comment: Have you used their postmaster tools to check your domain?

Comment: Yes, I have. I added my domain and verified it. It now shows up as a verified domain in the tools. However all of the reports say "No data at this time. Please come back later."

Comment: This is not a duplicate of referenced question. This one is about private emails. Accepted answer of referenced question is about mass emails and subscribe / unsubscribe.

Comment: If you have DMARC set up then Google will likely be sending reports to whatever address is configured to recieve them. Check those to see if Google highlights any issues there, may be able to see some kind of issue or misconfiguration there.

Comment: The Google DMARC reports do not tell me much sadly. Below is the output of the latest DMARC report which confirms that DKIM and SPF both passed, but doesn't tell me why the message was still rejected.

Comment: <policy_evaluated>
    <disposition>none</disposition>
    <dkim>pass</dkim>
    <spf>pass</spf>
    <reason>
      <type>sampled_out</type>
          <comment></comment>
        </reason>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>flanigan.net</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>flanigan.net</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>default</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>flanigan.net</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>